# Countdown timer resets on a new page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a simple battle game where two players select their characters and fight. The battle is divided into turns, each turn starts on the new page and has a timer which counts down from 99 to 0. However, I don't know how to make the timer preserve its time from the previous turn on the new page. Every time the new turn starts, the timer resets itself to 99.
Is there any way to fix this problem?

```
<script>
      let timeLeft = 99;
      let elem = document.getElementById('timer');
      let timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
      function countdown() {
          if (timeLeft == -1) {
              clearTimeout(timerId);
              doSomething();
          } else {
              elem.innerHTML = timeLeft;
              timeLeft--;
          }
        }
       function doSomething() {
          alert("Player x loses");
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Is having each turn on a new page a must? It is slow, and as you have found out, makes it troublesome to retain information.

Comment: save the `timeLeft` to localStorage using `localStorage.setItem()` & read it from localstorage using `localStorage.getItem()` functions

Comment: I suggest you put just enough code to produce a timer and a new page switching. Note you have a specialized HTML/JS/CSS snippet tool to use.

Comment: @MarcinBalejko, by 'new page' do you mean refresh/reload of page? If so, consider using local or session storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a small session variable and check for it at the beginning of each page load with an if statement. If the session variable is empty, set it to the value you want, otherwise, retain the previous value from the last time the script was run and start it from that last value.

```
<script>
var timeLeft;
if(!sessionStorage.getItem('timer'){
     timeLeft = 99;
} else {
     timeLeft = sessionStorage.getItem('timer');
}

      let elem = document.getElementById('timer');
      let timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
      function countdown() {
          if (timeLeft == -1) {
              clearTimeout(timerId);
              doSomething();
          } else {
              elem.innerHTML = timeLeft;
              timeLeft--;
              sessionStorage.setItem('timer', timeLeft);
          }
        }
       function doSomething() {
          alert("Player x loses");
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Glad I could help! One more note, the reason that I used sessionStorage instead of localStorage is that sessionStorage only stays while the browser is open. LocalStorage persists between browser sessions. So this way, if the user closes the browser and comes back to play later, there's a fresh variable instead of loading the timer from the previous play. Also, please don't forget to mark my answer correct :D

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, all Internet browsers limit the ability one page has to persist or affect changes on a new page. To allow otherwise would mean that a browser could link to a new page, then access variables and other state from that new page (things like usernames, etc).

There are a few solutions but all of them are somewhat complicated. First, you could use local browser storage (it looks like someone already posted some code for thsi so I will skip a sample). This would allow you to store the time remining on the previous timer into a cookie, then your new page could load this value and resume the timer.

Another example is to use embeded frames. So instead of opening a new page in a new tab or window, you would open that page within an iframe on your parent page. With an iframe both your child and parent pages have access to the global Window object, where you can store information such as timers and other variables.

However, the best approach is to not create a new page at all. Instead, refactor your game to load each turn the same page. Use app-like components such as modals to simulate the opening of a new window. There are a ton of components out there that will accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp):

```
<script> 
let timeLeft = localStorage.getItem("timeLeft");
if(!timeLeft){
timeLeft=99;}
let elem = document.getElementById('timer'); 
let timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
 function countdown() {
 if (timeLeft == -1) { 
clearTimeout(timerId); 
doSomething();
 } else { 
elem.innerHTML = timeLeft;
localStorage.setItem("timeLeft", timeLeft);
 timeLeft--; 
} } 
function doSomething() { 
alert("Player x loses"); 
} </script>
```

I used localStorage to set value of `timeLeft` because whenever you reload the page ,value of `timeLeft` gets reset.

Try to call variable in `localStorage` when page is reloaded.